# Why do negative numbers in variables have a larger limit than a positive number (signed variables)?

Tags: c++, variables, binary, range, negative-number

As seen in the picture above all of the variables have a negative limit that is one more than the positive limit. I was how it is able to add that extra one. I know that the first digit in the variable is used to tell if it is negative (1) or if is not (0). I also know that binary is based on the powers of 2. What I am confused about is how there is one extra when the positive itself can't go higher and the negative only has one digit changing. For example, a short can go up to 32,767 (01111111 11111111) or 16,383 + all of the decimal values of the binary numbers below it. Negative numbers are the same thing except a one at the beginning, right? So how do the negative numbers have a larger limit? Thanks to anyone who answers!

[image]

Comment: Negative starts at -1, but non-negative doesn't start at 1. Non-negative starts at 0.

Comment: Also, wherever you got this chart, those limits aren't correct for most modern systems.

Comment: That chart looks very old (being based on a system with 16-bit integers) and has so many errors that it is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is a scheme called "2's complement" to represent signed integer.

You know that the *most significant bit* of a signed integer represent the sign. But what you don't know is, it also represent a value, a *negative* value.

Take a 4-bit 2's complement signed integer as an example:

```
1     0    1    0
-2^3  2^2  2^1  2^0
```

This 4-bit integer is interpreted as:

```
  1 * -2^3  +  0 * 2^2  +  1 * 2^1  +  0 * 2^0
= -8 + 0 + 2 + 0
= -6
```

With this scheme, the max of 4-bit 2's complement is 7.

```
0     1    1    1
-2^3  2^2  2^1  2^0
```

And the min is -8.

```
1     0    0    0
-2^3  2^2  2^1  2^0
```

Also, 0 is represented by `0000`, 1 is `0001`, and -1 is `1111`. Comparing these three numbers, we can observe that *zero* has its "sign bit" positive, and there is no "negative zero" in 2's complement scheme. In other words, half of the range only consists of negative number, but the other half of the range includes zero and positive numbers.

Comment: Oh I see, the first binary digit in a signed number is a negative of its value so it would turn the whole number negative if it was a 1 due to the fact that it is double the size of the sum of all of the lower numbers. The positive numbers have a smaller limit because it is the sum of all of the numbers (1 less than the digit above) while the negatives can just have an extra place to have a full value of the largest digit. EX: 10000000 00000000 (-32, 768) as opposed to 01111111 11111111 (32,767). Thanks Nicky C!

Answer (score 2):

If integers are stored using *two's complement* then you get one extra negative value and a single zero.  If they are stored using *one's complement* or *signed magnitude* you get two zeros and the same number of negative values as positive ones.  Floating point numbers have their own storage scheme, and under IEEE formats use have an explicit sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the first digit in the variable is used to tell if it is negative (1) or if is not (0).

The first *binary* digit (or *bit*), yes, assuming two's complement representation. Which basically answers your question. There are 32,768 numbers < 0 (-32,768 .. -1) , and 32,768 numbers >= 0 (0 .. +32,767).

Also note that in binary the total possible representations (bit patterns) are an even number. You couldn't have the min and max values equal in absolute values, since you'd end up with an odd number of possible values (counting 0). Thus, you'd have to waste or declare illegal at least one bit pattern.